# Bower - How to install jquery.js only and not the whole package?

Tags: jquery, bower

Using `bower install jquery` command what I get in `jquery` folder are `dist` folder with `jquery.js` and `jquery.min.js`, `src` folder with the whole bunch of js files that make up jquery, I suppose, `bower.json` and licence files.
How could I install `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js` only?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-installer) and an extra "install" section in your `bower.json` file like:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "1.11.1",
        "normalize-css": "latest"
    },
    "install" : {
        "path"  : {
            "js": "_js/",
            "css": "_css/"
        }
    }
}
```

With that "install" section you can specify the install folder.
It than automatically creates the folders - if they're not existing - and installs just the required files like `jquery.js` or `normalize.css` to the specified "css" or "js" folder.

Comment: Please post a specific example for jquery

Comment: Isn't that example working for you @julmot ? Maybe the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26611521/1303917) of Colin below is more helpful.

Comment: No because in the repository is no "jquery.min.js" or "jquery.js" file. Don't know where the "dist"-folder comes from, however I am not able to filter only the dist-folder with this extension.

Comment: Kind of a tedious solution since most of the packages I use I have to customize which files are installed, but better than nothing

Comment: What about minified?

Answer (score 14):

You can also use this parameter:

```
"ignore": [
        "source",
        "spec",
        ".bowerrc",
        ".gitignore",
        ".jshintignore",
        ".jshintrc",
        "bower.json",
        "gruntfile.js",
        "package.json",
        "README.md"
    ],
```

This will ignore the unecessary files to work when you download files.

Comment: +1 However, an explanation of how & why this works would probably make this answer better understood & give you more upvotes

Answer (score 14):

From the [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/):

> The jQuery Bower package contains additional files besides the default
>   distribution. In most cases you can ignore these files, however if you
>   wish to download the default release on it's own you can use Bower to
>   install jQuery from one of the above urls instead of the registered
>   package. For example, if you wish to install just the compressed
>   jQuery 2.1.0, you can install just that file with the following
>   command:

`bower install http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js`

Comment: Not a great package name, strange index.js file, but it works perfectly

Comment: as @NicolasZozol points out this is indeed interesing but instead of creating a `jquery-2.1.0.min.js` file in the specified bower directory, it creates a directory named `jquery-2.1.0.min` with inside the `index.js` along with a `.bower.json` file. Looking at the latter file, I suppose the the former is named after the `"main": "index.js"` rule. Is there anyway to override this?

Comment: This works. (add a `--save`makes sense).
Also worked for me e.g. for `bower install https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js --save`