# Get only the compiled bootstrap css/js using bower or npm?

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install

I'm willing but prefer not to have to add in a gruntfile to compile bootstrap LESS into css before using them.  I'm a command-line kind of guy as well and I was wondering if there was a special distribution of bootstrap 3 that only came with compiled javascript and css that I could install using either bower or grunt?

Right now, I'm downloading the compiled stuff from the web.  Just wondering :)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10313 running `bower install bootstrap` should install:

- Files in dist directory;
- Files in js directory;
- Files in less directory;
- bower.json file;
- README.md file;
- LICENSE file.

Indeed  3.3.4 installs:

```
├── bower.json
├── dist
├── fonts
├── grunt
├── Gruntfile.js
├── js
├── less
├── LICENSE
├── package.js
├── package.json
└── README.md
```

Indeed the Grunt build system and the Less file are some "overhead". If you want to install only the files from `/dist` (which includes the compiled CSS and JS, including the fonts for the glyphicons-halflings) you should read [Bower - How to install jquery.js only and not the whole package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464049/bower-how-to-install-jquery-js-only-and-not-the-whole-package) and take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer

Ans possible also take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower

Comment: It certainly didn't use to!