# npm install minified version only

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I just installed Node with **npm** to use it for frontend dependency management. I know there is also *bower* but why would I need another package manager that is built on top of another?

When installing a package, npm seems to always load the full source of the js library into the `node_modules` directory. Just as it's downloading the complete github repository.

How do I install only the minifed (distribution) version of a javascript lib with **npm**?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/224828/105673. I don't know about npm but bower comes with minified version of packages.

Comment: The difference between `npm` and `bower` is mostly in the available repositories. `npm` is normally used for fetching backend modules (as nodejs normally runs as backend), while `bower` has repositories for frontend javascript libraries. Only getting the minified version isn't directly possible with `npm` AFAIK. For bower, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/368) for the described behavior. Or you could try with `ignore` all other file extensions than `.min.js` inside your `bower.json`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no standard way to ask `npm` to get the minified version of a library. Some developers will produce packages that contain *both* minified and unminified versions (that's what I've done for one of my projects, which is web-only but can be installed through `npm`) or will create a package that contains an unminified version and *another* package that contains the minified version. This is done on a case by case basis, varies from package to package, and has to be determined by looking at a project's documentation.

If a developer has not cared to provide a minified code base through `npm` then you'll have to perform the minification yourself or get the "official" minified code through some other means.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That points me to the question why many developers even include *unminified* js files into their npm packages. The ability of editing external dependencies locally sounds like an anitpattern to me. And including both versions makes a big package doesn't it?

Comment: ``npm`` was primary created for *backend* dependencies. I think most developers don't see much benefit to minifying backend packages, seeing as they live on servers where memory is cheap, and IO is fast. If someone could come up with a compelling study showing that minifying backend libraries would give significant benefits, then the folks responsible for ``npm`` might add support for having a standard way to request minified code. I do recall reading that they are thinking about improving ``npm`` for packaging client-side code. I don't have a URL to that discussion handy.

Comment: not a real solution, but still, take a look at ➪ http://stackoverflow.com/a/26611521/444255

Comment: @Louis A reason for minifying backend libraries is when you want to use them in something like AWS Lambda where the size of your application influences the start and execution time.

Comment: @Louis - "`npm` was primary created for backend dependencies" - that doesn't mean they shouldn't be minified. Java jars, for example, are also back-end dependencies, but they (typically) don't include all the source and tests with it because as the user of the library you have no need for them. There is no reason why NPM should install a hundred files when I need just one.

Comment: Non-minified version can be very useful when debugging the library usage - you can just go into the library and check what goes wrong.