# Workaround for NPM Package Missing Minified Scripts

Tags: jquery, npm, minify, package.json

I'm trying to use the [jquery-validation-unobtrusive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) NPM package. Unfortunately the package authors do not include the minified version of the script in question. They seem to exclude it using the `files` section in the `package.json`, even though the minified `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` does exist in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive):

```
"files": [
  "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
]
```

How can I override the above and force the download of the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` file from the package?

Comment: As per the answer found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447158/npm-install-minified-version-only, there is no way to tell the **npm** to download the minified version although we can create a grunt task or gulpfile to take all the Javascript, files inside the **node_modules** folder and **minify**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force npm to download the minified file. What was published by the authors is what you will receive when you install the package.

That said, npm can install a tarball and GitHub allows you to download a repostory as a tarball. You can depend on a tarball archive of the repository instead of `jquery-validation-unobtrusive`.

Using `jquery-validation-unobtrusive`:

```
tmp.pRVlIN3W $ npm i jquery-validation-unobtrusive
/tmp/tmp.pRVlIN3W
└─┬ jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.6 
  ├── jquery@3.1.1 
  └─┬ jquery-validation@1.15.1 
    └── jquery@2.2.4

tmp.pRVlIN3W $ tree node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive
node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
└── package.json

0 directories, 4 files
```

Using `https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/archive/master.tar.gz`:

```
tmp.PEJ4zTT6 $ npm i https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/archive/master.tar.gz
/tmp/tmp.PEJ4zTT6
└─┬ jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.6 
  ├── jquery@3.1.1 
  └─┬ jquery-validation@1.15.1 
    └── jquery@2.2.4 

tmp.PEJ4zTT6 $ tree node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/
node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── bower.json
├── gulpfile.js
├── jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
├── jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
└── package.json

0 directories, 8 files
```

(You can also depend on a particular version of the package this way by replacing `master` in the URL with a tag. See [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for more information.)