# "NPM Install" of only minified files in the module

Tags: module, npm, npm-install

I want to publish a module through npm.

I want to publish the .js and .min.js files in order for the npm to install each file separately depending on the environment.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

No. That would be a new npm feature or would require a separate package per device

Also see: [npm install minified version only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447158/npm-install-minified-version-only)